# Overriding base class type with derived type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, types

I have a baseclass called RottenFruit, a class called RottenApple that inherints from it.

Now i want the RottenFruit class to inherit a class called Fruit, which is a base class for the Apple class, so I can add a Fruit object under each RottenFruit object, making it generic in terms of the types of fruit.

```
abstract class RottenFruits : Fruit
{
    public virtual Fruit fruit { get; set; }; 
    bool isRotten { get; set; }
}

class RottenApple : RottenFruits
{
    public override Apple fruit { get; set; };
}
```

If i Try this I get an error in the derived class saying

> Type must be Fruit to match overridden member RottenFruits.fruit
>   Why dosen't the type match when Fruit is a baseclass of Apple?

**Edit:** 
Lets say I have multiple RottenFruits: RottenBanana, RottenPear, etc. and I want to gather them all in an array. RottenFruits will expect a type parameter of Fruit if I use a generic type

```
RottenFruits[] fruits = new { 
    new RottenApple(){fruit = new Apple()}, 
    new RottenBanana(){fruit = new Banana() 
}
```

Comment: @MongZhu you are correct, i edited my question

Comment: Basic C# rule, an override cannot have a different return type.  That is fundamentally type-unsafe.  Pretty evident from the intended usage, you have no idea whether fruits[1] is an Apple object and has a HasWorm property.  You have to cast, use the is or as operator to verify that is safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do the way you are trying it. i think what you can do is use generics here:

```
class Fruit
{
}
class abstract RottenFruits<T> : Fruit where T : class
{
    public T fruit; 
    bool isRotten { get; set; }
}
```

and now you can do it:

```
class RottenApple : RottenFruits<Apple>
{

}
```

Comment: No need for the property in the last code block or the comma in the constraint